# Software to extract branch data from directed network diagram

Tags: windows, linux, graphs

I have a network diagram (consider it to be directed) (see example below:)

[image]

I need a software that can extract the following info from the said diagram:

[image]

Is there a software that can do this type of thing?

---

EDIT (following Jan Doggen comment):

- My input is preferrably a drawing
- OS can either be Linux or Windows (though I have very little experience with Linux)
- I would prefer free open-source software as far as possible.

Comment: What is your input? The picture or an underlying data structure? If data structure, describe. What OS should this work on? What are you willing to pay? Please read http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information and [edit] all required information into your question.